# Background job with period lower than 15 minutes on ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I am building an app for ios in react native.

Using the [react-native-background-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-task) I am running a task that fetches data from a server.
On IOS the default and lowest period is 15 minutes, which is too high for what I need.
Is there a way to create a background task on IOS with a lower period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

iOS does not support frequently polling in the background as it is not battery or network friendly.

That module uses the iOS background fetch service which is the only supported background fetch facility on iOS.

With background fetch, iOS invokes you background fetch handler when it determines. This may be even less frequently than 15 minutes; the time interval you supply is a *requested interval* only and will be modified based on how often and when you server returns new data and other factors.

The preferred approach is to use a push notification when your server has new data.