# Sending push notification for background events in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, background, mobile-development

I am developing in flutter a stock market alert app that checks in the background a certain stock price and send a push notification. I used the [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) library but that is only able to fetch the price every 15 minutes, and have some reliability issues on ios.
Therefore, I was wondering if there was another way to implement the same feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try android_alarm_manager package from pub dev, but it is only available for
(you guessed it) android. This will solve the 15 min frequency I hope it works for you. On a side note I also need a function to run when user enters a geofence when app is on background and I still haven't found a solution. Because in my problem it shouldn't run every x minutes but when sth is triggered.

Comment: Thanks, btw I came across this article that looks like it fits your needs https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

Comment: yes, I've been trying to replicate it , but the author still says that the event doesn't trigger when he passes the geofence, but a random amount of time, after that, plus it didn't work for me

Comment: oh I see, probably the best solution in your case involves the use of an external device which constantly checks the gps coordinates since the app can't stay awake and, once the geofence is entered, it notifies the server which awake the app and perform the operation.

Answer (score 1):

there is this answer of a similar question but on IOS but it work the similar way on android  hope this help and i am sorry for this negative answer :(

[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44609931/14865120)